# jboss-as-maven-plugin deploy over https

Tags: ssl, deployment, jboss, remoting

I have a working remote deploy to JBOSS AS 7.1.  However, I want to send these deploys using ssl.  When I add server identity tag identifying the ssl information, my jboss instance will not receive the deploy.

```
<server-identities>
  <ssl>
    <keystore path="xxx/yyy/zzz.jks" password="myFakePassword"/>
  </ssl>
</server-identities>
```

Removing the above will allow me to deploy remotely, but it will not use ssl (my problem).

The above identity is required for access to the administrative console, so I know that it works.

Here is my configuration of the plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.Final</version>
    <configuration>
       <force>true</force>
        <hostname>domain.com</hostname>
        <port>9119</port> <!-- not the real port -->
        <username>myFakeUsername</username>
        <password>myFakePassword</password>
        <filename>deployable.war</filename>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

The error I get from the deploying client is:

[ERROR] }'. java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://domain.com:9119. The connection failed: General SSLEngine problem: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

and the error I get on the server log is:

ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "domain.com:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed:  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Other relevant information:

The certificate is self signed.  The certificate works for https requests to the admin console and to the web applications hosted on jboss.  The certificate works from the above mentioned identity when accessing the admin console through a browser.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue and resolved it by creating a truststore, adding my certificate to it, and then passing that truststore as a JVM argument when calling the Maven deploy command.

1. Create the truststore:

   > keytool -import -file path/to/your/certificate.cert -alias -keystore path/to/myTrustStore
2. Issue your command with that truststore as a JVM argument:

   > mvn jboss-as:deploy -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/myTrustStore